# Why does the first one work perfectly, but the second one has this error " 'int' object is not iterable". Ain't they the same thing?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

```
def narcissistic(value):
    return value == sum(int(x) ** len(str(value)) for x in str(value))
print(narcissistic(153))


def narcissistic(value):
    for x in str(value):
       return value == sum(int(x)**len(str(value)))
print(narcissistic(153))
```

Comment: The argument to `sum()` has to be a sequence. `int(x)**len(str(value))` is just a single integer.

Comment: You're also returning on the first iteration of the `for` loop, so you never test any of the other digits in `value`.

Comment: No they ain't the same thing at all

Answer (score 1):

The [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) expects an `iterable`, and in the second case `int(x)**len(str(value))` is only **one** int

The equivalent with a classif for loop would be

```
def narcissistic(value):
    result = 0
    for x in str(value):
        result += int(x) ** len(str(value))
    return result == value
```